# Onclick , onmouseover , onmouseout on 1 picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i have 10 images and i need to do on mouse over , on mouse out and to use on click to change the image and on the second click return back, **but without any special id for any image** ?? can you help !

Comment: Java tag removed as I don't see that this question has much to do with this language.

Comment: hello welcome to SO....you should understand what type of questions are here use this link...http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.. The community will help you once you have tried some codes and need help debugging it ....:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 'this' selector,

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    // Code to do when is mouse over (Mouse Enter)
    $(this).attr("src", urlImage);
},function(){
    // Code to do (Mouse Leave)
    $(this).attr("src", AnotherUrlImage);
});
```

This is the correct script for toggle image with click

```
$("img").one("click", click1);

function click1() {
    $(this).attr("src", "URLIMAGE2");
    $(this).one("click", click2);
}
function click2() {
    $(this).attr("src", "URLIMAGE2");
    $(this).one("click", click1);
}
```

Comment: Passing handlers to toggle is a good idea and seems like a very elegant way to solve this.

Comment: hello :) first of all i would like to thank you for your answer ,, but i have a problem that when i put the toggle script the images dissapper , can you tell me why please ?

Comment: Yeah, I try with this function and maybe isn't the better for that.
I edited my answer with a tested script. :)

Comment: hello viceente :) the hover script does not work with the click script .
any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can add a function to every `<img>` with this selector:

```
$('img').onclick(function(){
    //Some code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggle()` to do that on clicking the image.

```
$('img').toggle(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", BackImage);
    }, function() {
      $(this).attr("src", FrontImage);
});
```